# How to access "/dev/mem" from unprivileged lxc container?

Tags: 16.04, lxc

I know it sounds silly but I want to access '/dev/mem" from inside the unprivileged `lxc` container.
We have this gaming application that accesses "/dev/mem" and other hardware from similar device nodes either by mmap or by file IO.

To access such device nodes, we need root permissions. Up until now, we ran our gaming application as root.

But I am evaluating `lxc` container as a technology to deliver the application and would like to deliver it inside unprivileged container.

any idea how I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Accessing hardware or memory directly is always a privileged operation. What you can do: "virtualize" it by substituting your own driver for /dev/mem and implement whatever needed for that game, in isolated and secure way.